# ¿Cómo hacer que mi código escriba pero no borre lo que hay antes en un archivo?

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente código

```
 public void guardarArticulos(List<articulos> listaDeArticulos) throws IOException { 

  FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("articulos.dat", true);
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(output);
  out.writeObject(listaDeArticulos);
  out.close(); 
  System.out.println("Articulos guardados correctamente!");
 
  }
```

el cual guarda una lista de articulos que se cargan por consola en un archivo. El tema es que cuando vuelvo a ejecutar el programa y quiero cargar articulos nuevos en el archivo, se cargan por sobre los archivos ya cargados anteriormente y los elimina. Me gustaria que se carguen por debajo y que no modifiquen los archivos ya existentes, como podría hacer?

Probé con el fileWriter pero no lograba encontrar la forma de escribir el Arraylist ya que me tiraba un error.

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué error tenías con FileWriter? Aquí tienes un pequeño ejemplo de como podrías hacerlo con FileWriter:

```
File archivo = new File("articulos.dat");
FileWriter fout= new FileWriter(archivo, true);
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fout);
output.write("Esta linea se insertará al final del archivo articulos.dat");

output.close();
fout.close();
```

En todo caso pon  el código que utilizaste cuando probaste con FileWriter y tuviste problemas. Para grabar la lista deberías iterar por la list:

```
  for(articulos a : listaArticulos) {

           output.write(a.nombre + " " + a.precio); // algo parecido a esto
         }
```

Comment: Hice esto 
`public void guardarArticulos(List<articulos> listaDeArticulos) throws IOException{
 File archivo = new File(rutaArticulos);
 FileWriter fout= new FileWriter(archivo, true);
 BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(fout);
 
  for(articulos art : listaDeArticulos) {
         output.write(art.getNumero()+ " " + art.getCodigo()+ " " + art.getNombre() + " " + art.getPrecio() + " " + art.getStock()); 
       }
 
 output.close();
 fout.close();
 }` 
pero sigue sobreescribiendome los archivos :(

Comment: Acabo de probar el codigo que te envie y funciona la inserción al final del archivo. Lo único que tuve que ponerle fue un retorno de carro (\n). Quizá en otro lado de tu aplicación estás limpiando el archivo.

Comment: Logré guardarlo y que no se sobreescriba, ahora necesitaria poder mostrarlo por pantalla si el usuario quiere, por ejemplo, si escoje la opcion 2-Mostrar articulos, se imprima la lista de articulos guardados, como podría hacer?

Comment: ¿Cómo lo solucionaste?